I'm trying to parse .json in C++ using nlohmann/json library but it's failing during compilation
I'm trying to parse .json in C++ using nlohmann/json library on Ubuntu but during compilation it fails every time and I can't understand why it's happening like this, help!
yt_dlp_cpp.hpp
#pragma once

#ifndef YT_DLP_CPP_HPP
#define YT_DLP_CPP_HPP

#include <string>
#include <vector>

namespace yt_dlp_cpp
{
    struct format_info
    {
        std::string format_id, format_note, ext;
        size_t width, height;
    };

    class yt_dlp
    {
      public:
        yt_dlp();

        yt_dlp(const std::string &url);

        void set_url(const std::string &url);

        const std::vector<format_info> get_formats() const;

      private:
        struct info
        {
            std::string url;
        } info;

        std::vector<format_info> formats;
    };
} // namespace yt_dlp_cpp

#endif // YT_DLP_CPP_HPP

yt_dlp_cpp.cpp
#include <boost/process.hpp>
#include <memory>

#include "nlohmann/json.hpp"
#include "yt_dlp_cpp.hpp"

std::unique_ptr<nlohmann::json> yt_dlp_json_info;

inline void yt_dlp_parse_json_info(const std::string &url)
{
    boost::process::ipstream pipe_stream;
    boost::process::child c(
        "yt-dlp --no-playlist --skip-download --dump-json " + url,
        boost::process::std_out > pipe_stream
    );

    std::string temp_line, output;

    while (std::getline(pipe_stream, temp_line)) output += temp_line;

    c.wait();

    yt_dlp_json_info =
        std::make_unique<nlohmann::json>(nlohmann::json::parse(output));
}

inline void yt_dlp_init_formats(std::vector<yt_dlp_cpp::format_info> &formats)
{
    for (const auto &i : yt_dlp_json_info->at("formats"))
    {
        formats.push_back(
            {i["format_id"], i["format_note"], i["ext"],
             i["width"].get<size_t>(), i["height"].get<size_t>()}
        );
    }
}

yt_dlp_cpp::yt_dlp::yt_dlp() {}

yt_dlp_cpp::yt_dlp::yt_dlp(const std::string &url) { set_url(url); }

void yt_dlp_cpp::yt_dlp::set_url(const std::string &url)
{
    yt_dlp_parse_json_info(url);
    yt_dlp_init_formats(formats);
    info.url = url;
}

const std::vector<yt_dlp_cpp::format_info>
    yt_dlp_cpp::yt_dlp::get_formats() const
{
    return formats;
}

main.cpp
#include <iostream>

#include "yt_dlp_cpp.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    yt_dlp_cpp::yt_dlp yt_dlp("https://youtu.be/Sab6wfnmTcY?si=wE-kXRdHtlNLxVE0"
    );

    for (const auto &i : yt_dlp.get_formats()) cout << i.ext << endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

So I compiled this code using xmake and every time I'm getting compilation error...
Compilation error
main: nlohmann/json.hpp:21450: const value_type& nlohmann::json_abi_v3_11_3::basic_json<ObjectType, ArrayType, StringType, BooleanType, NumberIntegerType, NumberUnsignedType, NumberFloatType, AllocatorType, JSONSerializer, BinaryType, CustomBaseClass>::operator[](const typename nlohmann::json_abi_v3_11_3::basic_json<ObjectType, ArrayType, StringType, BooleanType, NumberIntegerType, NumberUnsignedType, NumberFloatType, AllocatorType, JSONSerializer, BinaryType, CustomBaseClass>::object_t::key_type&) const [with ObjectType = std::map; ArrayType = std::vector; StringType = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; BooleanType = bool; NumberIntegerType = long int; NumberUnsignedType = long unsigned int; NumberFloatType = double; AllocatorType = std::allocator; JSONSerializer = nlohmann::json_abi_v3_11_3::adl_serializer; BinaryType = std::vector<unsigned char>; CustomBaseClass = void; nlohmann::json_abi_v3_11_3::basic_json<ObjectType, ArrayType, StringType, BooleanType, NumberIntegerType, NumberUnsignedType, NumberFloatType, AllocatorType, JSONSerializer, BinaryType, CustomBaseClass>::const_reference = const nlohmann::json_abi_v3_11_3::basic_json<>&; typename nlohmann::json_abi_v3_11_3::basic_json<ObjectType, ArrayType, StringType, BooleanType, NumberIntegerType, NumberUnsignedType, NumberFloatType, AllocatorType, JSONSerializer, BinaryType, CustomBaseClass>::object_t::key_type = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; nlohmann::json_abi_v3_11_3::basic_json<ObjectType, ArrayType, StringType, BooleanType, NumberIntegerType, NumberUnsignedType, NumberFloatType, AllocatorType, JSONSerializer, BinaryType, CustomBaseClass>::object_t = std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, nlohmann::json_abi_v3_11_3::basic_json<>, std::less<void>, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, nlohmann::json_abi_v3_11_3::basic_json<> > > >]: Assertion `it != m_data.m_value.object->end()' failed.
error: execv(/home/sasha/yt_dlp_cpp/build/linux/x86_64/debug/main ) failed(-1)


That's an assertion that happens a run-time, not a compiler error. Use a debugger to catch it, and find out where in your code it happens. Examine variables and their values in your code to see what might be wrong.

And a general tip to help with these kind of problems: Don't write large pieces of code all and once. Start with an empty main function. Build with extra warning enabled and treated as errors. When it builds cleanly, then test as much as you can, with all kinds of inputs (valid, invalid, and just weird). When it passes all tests, then add a very small bit of code, perhaps even just one or two lines. Build and test as before. This will make it much easier to detect, debug and fix problems as they occur.

Another general tip: Don't try to do too much all at once in the program. For example, don't make constructors that does initialization as well as web-requests and parsing the received data. Split it up into actual initialization, and then a new function which does the "work". Also try to avoid things like sub-processes or threads as long as possible, add them only when absolutely needed. Sub-processes and threads can complicate things quite a lot. Start simple, only add complexity when needed.

@john I wrote this code by myself

@АлександрАлибеков OK I'll delete my comment.

Too large for a comment, so try add it here instead.
The assert comes from this function:
/// @brief access specified object element
/// @sa https://json.nlohmann.me/api/basic_json/operator%5B%5D/
const_reference operator[](const typename object_t::key_type& key) const
{
    // const operator[] only works for objects
    if (JSON_HEDLEY_LIKELY(is_object()))
    {
        auto it = m_data.m_value.object->find(key);
        JSON_ASSERT(it != m_data.m_value.object->end());  // line 21450
        return it->second;
    }

    JSON_THROW(type_error::create(305, detail::concat("cannot use operator[] with a string argument with ", type_name()), this));
}

Seems like it is looking for a key, and it is just not there.
Alternatively, the code tries to add the key using container[key] = value;, but the container is const.

Okay, I found a solution to this... Every time scanning JSON I need to just check if a variable key exists in it...
